# npm install appium -g / saveError ENOENT ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, automated-tests, ubuntu-14.04, appium

I want install appium in ubuntu 14.04.
i have installed

1. node v8.4.0
2. npm 5.3.0
3. nvm v8.4.0

when i run `npm install -g appium`
i get `WARN`

`npm WARN deprecated babel-core@5.8.24: Babel 5 is no longer being maintained. Upgrade to Babel 6.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated line-numbers@0.2.0: Copy its ~20 LOC directly into your code instead.
/home/fadhlimaulidri/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin/appium -> /home/fadhlimaulidri/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/appium/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`

maybe i must upgrade babel-core

when i don't find how to upgrade to Babel 6. and then i run 
`npm install --save-dev babel-core`

and i get WARN

`npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/fadhlimaulidri/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/fadhlimaulidri/package.json'
npm WARN fadhlimaulidri No description
npm WARN fadhlimaulidri No repository field.
npm WARN fadhlimaulidri No README data
npm WARN fadhlimaulidri No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, Appium is not compatible with node version 8.4.0 which includes the npm with version 5.3.0.

I suggest you try to with stable node build which is Version: v6.11.2 (includes npm 3.10.10)